# What is the most reliable way to copy access front end files to client PCs

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, database, microsoft-access

I have several in house databases which have access 2003 front ends, either adp or ade files. I need to copy these from my server to every client machine.

In the past I have used a rollout scripts to copy the files to the all users desktop folder. I have since adapted this to also copy files to the public desktop folder since we started having windows 7 client machines as well as XP.

The problem is that some of the time these scripts don't work for windows 7.

Is there a better way of copying these files to a mix of windows 7 and XP clients or is using rollout scripts the best way?

Comment: If your script doesn't work sometimes, fix your script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Years after I first encountered this problem I finally have a solution.

My script was running as a computer startup script in Group Policy moving it to be a user logon script fixed it. No idea why I didn't try this before.

Answer (score 2):

It really makes no difference whether they're Access front ends or any other kind of file, the process is exactly the same. Just create a batch file, or whatever kind of script you prefer, and fire that off from the logon script if the destination is in the user space or a machine startup script otherwise.